# APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​ Your app is uploading users' Primary Account information

Tags: google-play-console, privacy-policy

At first the sata application was accepted by google play until several releases. However, at the time of doing the 12th release, my app was removed from google play.

APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​
Your app is uploading users' Primary Account information to https:.......... without posting a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.

how to solve it?, i need help immediately. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is clear:

1. You need a Privacy Policy
2. You need to add the Privacy Policy:

- In the app itself
- On the Play Developer Console

You have multiple options how to link to your Privacy Policy from within your app: About or Settings screen, Sign-up or Login screens, separate item in the menu etc.

[image]

When you add the Privacy Policy on Play Developer Console it would be made available on your app listing page:

[image]

You can read Google's requirements for having a Privacy Policy on this help page here:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#privacy

Comment: The solution is not so clear. We have a clear Privacy policy for users (in registration, on website, in Google Play, in app settings...), but Google rejected our app just because we send user's email to our own servers hosted on Amazon AWS.

Comment: How did you fix it?